# Repeat part of program while other part stays the same

Tags: batch-file, chat, repeat

I made a chat program and I want it to auto refresh so i can get rid of the refresh option I have on it. the only problem is I would need to have everything from `:A` all to way to `Echo -----....` to repeat itself while everything below does not. And I do not want it to be split into 2 files.

```
 :A
    cls
    Echo Server: %S%
    Echo Press Q to Quit Or Press R to refresh chat log.
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------
    type %S%.txt
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------
    set /p M=Enter Your Message:
    if "%M%"=="Q" goto B
    if "%M%"=="q" goto B
    if "%M%"=="R" goto A
    if "%M%"=="r" goto A
    echo %U%: %M% >>%S%.txt
    goto A
```

Answer (score 0):

Note

- `if /I` [Do a case Insensitive string comparison](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html);
- `:eof`  [This predefined label will exit the current routine](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html);
- `call :label` [Jump to a label (subroutine) in the current batch script](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html).

Next code snippet could help.

```
:A
    call :repeatHeader
    set /p "M=Enter Your Message: "
    if /I "%M%"=="Q" goto :B
    if /I "%M%"=="R" (
        call :refreshLog
        goto :A
    )
    echo %U%: %M% >>%S%.txt
    goto :A

:repeatHeader
    Echo Server: %S%
    Echo Press Q to Quit Or Press R to refresh chat log.
goto :eof

:refreshLog
    cls
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------
    type %S%.txt
    echo ---------------------------------------------------------
goto :eof

:B
```

Comment: i'm looking for it to work like... 1. Server name 2. Log 3 Enter Message... I only want 2 to repeat and the rest to stay the same.

Comment: I do not understand, sorry. I hope you have a template how to achieve your target using `call` statements to _learn by example_. Move, change or exchange commands within `:repeatHeader` and `:refreshLog` subroutines as you like it... Add  more procedure(s) if necessary...